# How do I make a PDFView start at the top of the document?

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently I am using a PDFView in my swift application, however when I instantiate the view controller that uses the PDFView, it always opens the pdf slightly scrolled down. For example:

[image]
[image]

The first image is how it opens, and the second image is the way I would like it to open. I can simply scroll up to have it look like the image on the right, however I wanted to know if there was any way of automatically doing it.
Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let pdfView = PDFView()

        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pdfView)

        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        guard let url = item?.url else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: url, withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

        if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you adding the pdf to the view? My guess is that the pdfview is somehow under the navigation bar

Comment: Adding to @GabrielPires comment. Check you're aligning the view to the safe area. Adding your code relevant to adding the view would also be helpful.

Comment: @HarryJ sorry about that, it totally slipped my mind to include the code. To be honest I don't fully understand the code since I took most of it from a youtube tutorial, however based on what I have, it seems to me like the constraints should be set to the safe area.

Comment: @FélixC.T. could you try just initializing `let pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.bounds)` and then deleting the 4 lines where you set the constraints and see if that works?

Comment: @GabrielPires that works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I solve it adding the following line:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // this line
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

    let pdfView = PDFView()()
    ...
}
```

That line stops your view going under the navigation bar

Comment: Nice. This worked for me as well. I'm curious though. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my PDF Document.

It looks like the document within the PDF Viewer simply ignored the top-anchor of the PDF Viewer and ended up favouring the top of the device and thus you have the top part of the document under the navigation bar.

The way I solved it was to add a UIView to the view-controller and anchor it all around to the 'safeAreaLayoutGuide' of the view-controller, then add the PDFView to that UIView and pin it to all the edges. Seems like a long winded approach, but it works.

The code below shows the basic implementation.

```
lazy var pdfView: PDFView = {
    let pdf = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    pdf.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdf.displayDirection = .vertical
    pdf.scaleFactor = pdf.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
    pdf.autoScales = true
    pdf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pdf.setValue(true, forKey: "forcesTopAlignment")
    return pdf
}()

let pdfContentView = UIView()
view.addSubview(pdfContentView)
pdfContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([pdfContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                             pdfContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
                             pdfContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
                             pdfContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)])

pdfContentView.addSubview(pdfView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContentView.topAnchor),
                                 pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContentView.bottomAnchor),
                                 pdfView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContentView.widthAnchor),
                                 pdfView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContentView.centerXAnchor)])
```

Comment: pdf.setValue(true, forKey: "forcesTopAlignment") is a Private function and I don't recommend using them. Apple can reject your application on review